# Connecting to a MongoDB instance running in GKE via a GUI

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I'm running a k8s cluster on google cloud.
I have a deployment running mongoDB.
I'd like to connect to this DB locally (to use a GUI for example).

I'm aware that I can do something like
I can do

```
kubectl get pods

kubectl exec -it <name of mongo db pod > sh

mongo
```

But what if I wanted to use a GUI?

I created a nodeport service as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orders-nodeport-mongo-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: orders-mongo-pod
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017 # mongo listens for traffic at this port
      targetPort: 27017
      nodePort: 31113
```

Then

```
kubectl get services
```

i see

> orders-nodeport-mongo-service NodePort 10.20.6.146 
> 27017:31113/TCP 15m

But when i try to connect to

```
mongo --host 10.20.6.146:31113
```

It doesn't work.. I'm doing something stupid here and I can't figure it out

As an FYI, here is my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: orders-mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: orders-mongo-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: orders-mongo-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: orders-mongo-container
          image: mongo
```

Answer (score 1):

`10.20.6.146` is a cluster IP. To connect to the NodePort you would need to know the node public IP. Normally, to access services from outside of the cluster, you would create an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource or change the service type to LoadBalancer (see [Exposing an External IP Address to Access an Application in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/)).

For debugging purposes you can use [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/):

```sh
# This call will block. The first 27017 is a local port and can be any free port.
kubectl port-forward deployment/orders-mongo-deployment 27017:27017

# In another console run
mongo --host localhost:27017
```